# Convert iPhone images to HEIF?

Tags: photos.app, ios

Now that iOS 11 supports HEIC images as first-class citizens, I'm wondering if there's any way to convert existing JPEG images from the camera to the new format?

My wife's iPhone 6 is stuffed to the gills, and the vast majority of it is photos. Upgrading them in-place would save many gigs.

Comment: That's not a duplicate, this question is about *doing it on the iPhone*.

Comment: I do it pretty simple way. Finding the image itself, then `copy` of the image, and then pasting in the application, which doesn't support HEIC yet. It works like a charm.